# Generate CloudPageURL for use outside marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

I have a Marketing CloudPage form that captures data and updates the existing records Salesforce using the UpdateSalesforceObject parameter. Subscribers access the page via CloudPageURL from the Marketing Cloud email.

We now have an added requirement to direct subscribers to this page using text messaging outside of marketing cloud. I need to be able to create a link combination that also gets them to this page.

I tried to create the ‘CloudpageURL’ using a few combinations including domain+sitepath + subscriber key example.com/consentformpage?id=003H47 but all gave me an error 500 on the page.

Comment: Are you passing all the parameters that are later used in the script? How do you retrieve those parameters in your script?

Comment: I am not passing additional parameters in the CloudPageUrl, just CloudPageURL(PageID). I am using RetrieveSaleforceObjects on the cloud page to display certain information based on Salesforce fields.

Comment: CloudPagesURL function passes a bunch of parameters itself, so if you want to redirect someone to the CloudPage from an external source, you need to make sure that all required parameters are passed - for instance, the Contact/Lead Id if you’re retrieving data from Sales Cloud. Can you post the script from your CloudPage?

Comment: yes, I can post the script. Looking into what you said about ensuring I have all of the required parameters, I see I do have additional (extra) parameters in the RetrieveSalesforceObject and UpdateSingleSalesforceObject that are not captured in input or hidden fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the [CloudPagesURL](https://ampscript.guide/cloudpagesurl/) function by default passes along a bunch of parameters:

> This function provides a convenient method of linking to landing pages
>   (created in CloudPages) from email messages.
>
> When an email is sent that includes a link to a landing page with this
>   function, a URL link is generated to the landing page and is appended
>   with an encrypted query string.
>
> This encrypted query string provides a reference to the email, which
>   means that [system personalization strings](https://ampscript.guide/personalization-strings-overview/) can be used on a landing
>   page to retrieve values related to the sent email. And as the string
>   is encrypted, no Subscriber information is passed in clear text.

Now if you want to redirect someone to a CloudPage from an external source, and you have a script on the CloudPage that uses any of the system personalization strings, for example, the subscriber key - you need to make sure you pass them as parameters in the URL.

For example, if you were setting a subscriber key variable in your script:

```
SET @subscriberkey = _subscriberkey
```

You will now need to pass it in the URL:

```
https://pub.s10.exacttarget.com/mycloudpage?subscriberkey=0031t000005D98UAAS
```

And in your script, retrieve it using the [QueryParameter](https://ampscript.guide/queryparameter/) function:

```
SET @subscriberkey = QueryParameter('subscriberkey')
```

If possible, avoid passing sensitive data in cleartext. Take a look at the encryption/decryption AMPscript functions to see if you would be able to use any of them to obfuscate personal data:

https://ampscript.guide/encryption-and-encoding-functions/